# How to make different Django form input buttons display on same line

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am using two separate Django forms on a page I am working on and I am wanting the input buttons to show up on the same line. Currently, they are stacking. I tried using CSS styling to use the inline-block but I don't think that's working because they are in separate forms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="song_edit.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="form1"> {% csrf_token %}
    <li>{{ file_name }}</li>
    <li>{{ form.as_p }}</li>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Download" name="save" id="download" />
</form>
<form action="/path/" method="get" id="form2">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="next" value="Next" id="Next" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8140gdv/)

Comment: Why you using forms if you ain't sending data to a server ?

Comment: I was originally planning on saving the data in the database and retrieving it later but realized it wasn't necessary to do so. So there's an easier way to do so without using Django forms?

Comment: Anyway, You want the forms to be next to each other use `inline-block` on both forms https://jsfiddle.net/fuo6ybq4/

Comment: If your forms are in `<li>`, Consider adding `display: inline-block;` to the `<li>`s themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bo1zg4yh/) what are you want with buttons?Just your form need display inline

```
  form{
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: or `class="d-inline-block"` since bootstrap is being used